# Is this reducible to a standard optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

There are $N$ agents who needs to be allocated $K$ discrete resources. There is a bottleneck threshold utility $R$ per agent. The $i$th agent has utility $r_{ij}$ if he is allocated $j$th resource. The objective is to allocate resources in order to maximize the number of agents who could exceed the threshold utility. Mathematically,

$$
\max_{x_{ij}}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbf{1}_{\sum_{j=1}^{K}x_{ij}r_{ij}>R}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ij}\le 1 \;\;\forall j\in\{1,2,\cdots, K\}\\
x_{ij}\in\{0,1\}
$$

$x_{ij}$ denotes whether $i$th agent is allocated $j$th resource. First equation maximizes the number of agents who exceed R utility. Second equation makes sure each resource is allocated to maximum one agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easily written as a MILP through standard big-M modelling. Introduce  new binary variables $E_i$ and the constraints

$\sum_{j=1}^{K}x_{ij}r_{ij} \geq R - M(1-E_i)$

where $M$ is a sufficiently large constant (but as small as possible) to ensure the constraint is redundant when $E_i$ is $0$ (standard big-M arguments). Now maximize $\sum E_i$. Note that you cannot use strict inequalities.

If $r_{ij}\geq 0$, $M=R$ works and the right-hand side simplifies to $RE_i$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help..Its awesome :). I don't know MILP much. So E_i can only be 0 or 1? Can MILP be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: Yes $E_i$ is a binary variable. No, MILPs can in general not be solved in polynomial time, they constitute the core of intractable combinatorial  problems.

Comment: Another question, Can i not set $M$ to just $R$? so $\sum x_{ij}r_{ij}≥RE_i$ should be okay? $x_{ij}$ and $r_{ij}$ are all positive numbers in my problem.

Comment: That's precisely what I say in the answer.

Comment: Oh hehe..my bad.. I didn't read it till the end :). Thanks. You are awesome

Comment: One last question. I did some research, Isn't this problem just Integer Linear Programming? Why Mixed? All unknowns are integers

Comment: Yes, MILP is just a more commonly used name, ILP is a special case.

Comment: Thanks so much. You have been very patient and helpful.